# WordPress Errors after Host Migration

Tags: php, migration

Total WordPress newb here, you guys. I recently moved WordPress files from BlueHost to GoDaddy. All was well on BlueHost. I moved the following files to GoDaddy.

- wp-content
- wp-admin
- wp-include
- All root files including wp-config.php

Most of the site appears to work, however `wp-admin` is hosed. There is also an error on each of the public facing WordPress pages. Here are the errors I am receiving:

> **WP-Admin error**
>   **Warning:** `call_user_func_array()` expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function '`ssjp_Init`' not found or invalid function name in `/file directory/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php` on line 429
>   **Warning:** Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at `/file diectory/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php:429`) in `/file directory/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php` on line 896

The WordPress codex forum suggests it is an issue with encoding, special characters or a lack of `?>` at the end of these files. I have tried to fix all of this with no avail. I have also quadruppled checked the `wp-config.php` file for errors.

Any suggestions would be awesome!

Comment: Disable all plugins and see if you can get into wp-admin.  My guess is an errant plugin is causing problems.  For example there might be a system specific setting in a plugin and causes it to break on another system.

Comment: @user42826 my man! You are a genius. Yes, all plugins are disabled now, but you have solved the problem. Why WordPress places all plugin IDs in one field is a mystery to me but you have solved my problem. THANK YOU. Feel free to post your comment as an answer so I can mark it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable all plugins and see if you can get into wp-admin. My guess is an errant plugin is causing problems. For example there might be a system specific setting in a plugin and causes it to break on another system

Comment: A plugin named - slippy slider.

Comment: Glad to see my suggestion helped and you figured out your problem!